# Getting the max value from a fact?

Tags: prolog

I have the following code in Prolog:

```
designer(name("Ivan", "Ivanov"), "Bulgarian", 12, 11).
designer(name("John", "Turturro"), "Italian", 2, 9).
designer(name("John", "McLane"), "American", 32, 26).
designer(name("Roberto", "Turturro"), "Italian", 32, 8).
designer(name("Petar", "Petrov"), "Bulgarian", 32, 23).

designer_max_points(FirstName, LastName, Points) :-
  designer(name(FirstName, LastName), _, _, Points),
  not(designer(name(_,_), _,_, Points1), Points1 > Points).
```

My goal is to get the maximum points value from each designer fact (the last value).

The solution above works, but I'm not sure why. I've researched the **not** predicate and apparently it succeeds whenever its arguments fail (for example **?-not(2=3).** will return true).

But if this is the case:

```
designer_max_points(FirstName, LastName, Points) :-
  designer(name(FirstName, LastName), _, _, Points),
  designer(name(_, _), _,_, Points1),
  Points > Points1.
```

... why doesn't this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it answers a different question:

> *Is there any designer having more points than any other?*

It will succeed with many duplicated answers, for instance

`name("Ivan", "Ivanov")` has more points than `name("John", "Turturro")` and `name("Roberto", "Turturro")`, so you should get two times

```
FirstName='Ivan', LastName='Ivanov', Points=11
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Can you explain what exactly happens in the not predicate, though?

Comment: mmh... *exactly* is a big word... see this wikipedia article about [Negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because all it does it succeed for *each* combination of 2 designers for whom the constraint holds true. What you want to do is something like this:

```
designer_max_points( Name, Surname , Points ) :-
  findall(d(N,S,P) , designer(name(N,S),_,_,P) , Ds ) , % get the list of info you need
  max_in_list(Ds,d(Name,Surname,Points))                % then scan it to find the desired value
  .

max_in_list( [D|Ds],M) :- max_in_list(Ds,D,M) . % get find the max value in the list, invoke the worker predicate using the head of the list as the current max.

max_in_list( [] , M , M ) .                        % once the source list is exhausted, the current max is the final max
max_in_list( [d(N,S,P)|Ds] , d(Nm,Sm,Pm) , M ) :-  % otherwise...
  ( P > Pm -> T1 = d(N,S,P) ; T1 = d(Nm,Sm,Pm) ) , % pick the new current max (T1),
  max_in_list(Ds,T1,M)                             % then recurse down on the tail.
  .                                                % easy!
```